# Das Upvoten unabhängig von Duplikatmarkierung in Betracht ziehen

Tags: discussion, duplicates, votes

Ich bin über die Frage

[jemand anderen, jemanden anderes](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44127/jemand-anderen-jemanden-anderes)

gestolpert, die (zu Recht) als Duplikat markiert wurde. An sich habe ich die Frage interessant gefunden und sie demzufolge positiv bewertet, aber das tut hier zur Sache nichts.

Pauschal:

*Sollten wir nicht auch das positiv Stimmen (das Upvoten) unabhängig davon machen, ob die Fragen schon vorher gestellt wurden?* Im Endeffekt hat ein Nutzer ihre/seine Zeit darin investiert.

(Es ist gewissermaßen eine Aufforderung.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jeder, der eine Frage interessant und wertvoll findet, soll sie auch upvoten. Nur weil es ein Duplikat gibt, ist das noch lange kein Grund, eine Frage nicht positiv zu bewerten.

Immerhin sind diese Fragen wertvolle "Hinweisschilder", die man unter Umständen schneller finden kann, als die verlinkte Frage.

Comment: Stimmt. Noch wichtiger ist aber klarzustellen, dass "duplicate" status per se kein Grund für downvotes ist. (Obwohl repost & exact duplicate da anders bewertet werden könnten: "lack of prior research effort, on this site, evidently")

Comment: full  ack <filler>

Answer (score 3):

Advocatus Diaboli postuliert eine hypothetische Unterstellung:

Es gibt hier Leute, die die Jagd nach Rep höher einschätzen als den Spaß am Fragen und Antworten. Wollen wir tatsächlich solche Leute dazu ermuntern, sich einfach hoch bewertete Fragen rauszusuchen und als Duplikat neu zu stellen?

Ich würde ein Duplikat nicht downvoten. Aber auch nicht upvoten (zumindestens dann nicht, wenn die Suche nach einer existierenden gleichen Frage mit ein paar Schlüsselworten einfach gewesen wäre).

Comment: Klar wäre auch, dass wenn das System das Duplikat nicht findet, wäre auch nicht die Schuld des Nutzers, eine Frage zu duplizieren. Machmal sind Beispiele (im Titel oder im Text) halt anhand anderer Nomen erklärt: da ist keine Suchmaschine fähig. Außerdem ist es gut, dass du das sagst (+1). Nutzer mit Rep haben mehr Rechte und könnten diese Seite misbrauchen. Optimal wäre es, dass man beurteilt, ob der OP tatsächlich eine Frage absichtlich dupliziert. Und das ist meines Erachtens nicht besonders kompliziert. In dem Fall würde ich auch nicht +1-stimmen

Comment: So meine ich das - Manchmal ist es ziemlich schwierig, Duplikate zu finden, weil das System anscheinend auf manche Schlüsselworte stärker anspringt als auf andere. Da kann ja dann der Nutzer nichts dafür. Wenn es aber offensichtlich ist, dass der Nutzer sogar gewarnt wurde, dass er ein Duplikat erzeugt, dann ist das eher sogar ein Grund zum Downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Der Tooltiptext beim mouseover für Upvotes besagt:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear.

Ein Duplikat zeigt keine eigene Nachforschungsleistung und sollte daher nicht aufgewertet werden.

Zwar mag es sein, dass die Person sehr wohl nachgeforscht hat, aber aus Gründen, die sie nicht selbst zu verantworten hat, das betreffende Posting nicht gefunden hat. Das lässt sich aber, außer es ist explicit glaubwürdig dargestellt, von den Besuchern nicht beurteilen.

Insbesondere sind die User nicht gehalten ein Zeitinvestment zu belohnen. Die User sind keine Kleinkinder, die beim Laufenlernen emotional gepeppelt werden müssen, um den Antrieb nicht zu verlieren.

Wer die Nützlichkeit eines Postings deshalb bejaht, weil es alternative Auffindemöglichkeiten bietet, der müsste die Leute ermutigen mehr Duplikate mit Absicht zu erzeugen, denn das ist die Aufgabe der Up- und Downvotes: Verhalten zu befördern und zu bremsen, um die Postings zu steuern.

Man müsste dann die Leute ermutigen Fragen zu verfassen, die es gar nicht darauf anlegen, neue Antworten zu generieren, sondern gleich geschlossen online gehen mit dem entsprechenden Link zum bereits beantworteten Postings.

Ob eine gute Frage durch das Duplikat häufig gefunden werden wird, ohne dabei das direkte Finden des Originals zu behindern, ist auch kaum vorherzusagen.

Es genügt m.E. eine Frage, die ein Duplikat ist, zum Schließen zu empfehlen ohne sie abzuwerten um dem Frager einen Gefallen zu tun, der ihn dann doch für seine Arbeit entschädigt.